# module object has no attribute oauth

Tags: python, twitter, oauth

I am trying to use the twitter library to pull some tweets but I am unable to get my authorization correctly. This is my code

```
import twitter
consumer_key = ''
consumer_secret = ''
access_token = '' 
access_secret = ''
t = Twitter( auth = OAuth(access_token, access_secret, consumer_key, consumer_secret))
api = twitter.Twitter( auth = auth )
print api
```

It is throwing AttributeError:'module' object has no attribute 'oauth'. I am simply pasting code from twitter help but then why is it not working?

Comment: Please show the complete traceback.

Comment: Which API are you using and which OAuth method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing which library you are using I'm going to assume you are using [this one](https://github.com/sixohsix/twitter) because the syntax looks the same. The error being thrown suggests that you are not importing the module that handles oauth. You could import all modules by adding this to the top of your code:

```
from twitter import *
```

This isn't really recommended because you might not need every module in the library so just import the ones you need e.g.:

```
from twitter import oauth
```

Comment: Also, the OP is probably mixing `twitter` and `python-twitter`, installed one and trying to use another.

Comment: I have installed only twitter and not python-twitter. So there is no mixing between them.

Comment: @ssbrewster I used first of the two options(as I am also importing Twitter from twitter). Now it is throwing a different error named 'twitter is not defined' in line 7 in file m1.py i.e. in line        api = twitter.Twitter( auth = auth )

Comment: I think you can probably just write `api = t(auth=auth)` because you've assigned the instance of the Twitter class you have created to the variable `t`. Which part of the documentation are you taking the code from?

Comment: @ssbrewster: from twitter import * works. I made a stupid mistake. Your suggestion works fine. One more question what is the difference between t and api in my code?

Comment: @AbhishekSharma well spotted you don't need both. If you print both they should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

As I am using import twitter I need to suffix twitter in front of any classname or any function of any class belonging to module twitter. This is the correct code:

```
import twitter
consumer_key = ''
consumer_secret = ''
access_token = ''
access_token_secret = ''
t = twitter.Twitter( auth = twitter.oauth.OAuth(access_token, access_token_secret, consumer_key, consumer_secret))
print t
```